# howto breadcrumbs/progress meter bar

Tags: jquery

My goal is to have a sort of breadcrumbs similar to this one

[image]

it's a clickable progress meter ...

here a start: http://jsfiddle.net/3z7Lsbdd/3/

every `li a` have a `data-index`.

What I want is, when I click a link, all the `li` that have `data-index <= clicked index` become red ( add the class `survey selected`)

```
$(".surveybreadcrumbs li a").click(function () {
         ????   
        }
        )
```

any help is welcome .

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Your fiddle demo is empty and there is no html shown in the question

Comment: Your JSFiddle is empty

Comment: Oooops !  I will update the fiddle in few minutes

Comment: sorry here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3z7Lsbdd/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be something like:

```
$(".surveybreadcrumbs li a").click(function () {
     var clickindex = $(this).data('index');
     $(".surveybreadcrumbs li a").each(function (i, val) {
            if  ( $(this).data('index') <= clickindex )
                $(this).addClass("surveyselected");
            else
                $(this).removeClass("surveyselected");
     });
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3z7Lsbdd/4/